# Google API OCR Language Hint

Tags: ocr, google-vision

I am using the Googel Vision API to detect English.
However, Korean cannot be detected.
I am using bitmap image for recognition. It is source.

TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder (this) .build ();
Frame imageFrame = new Frame.Builder ()
   .setBitmap (bitmap)
                .build ();
SparseArray  textBlocks = textRecognizer.detect (imageFrame);

In the case of Google Vision API, if  use Language Hint,  need to communicate (json) with Google Cloud ???

Comment: Here is a doc on Vision API language hints: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages Does that help? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You can use Language Hint by using the class of annotateRequest. But I want to use Reconize Class, not annotateReques class. Because annotateRequest Class must be online, Reconize Class can be used offline. However, perhaps Reconize Class only supports English. And if you use annotateRequest Class, OCR is not fast.